# Not working: override the default less-than operator of shared_ptr of a class

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, shared-ptr, multiset

all.  I'm trying to use a `std::multiset` to have automatic ordering upon insertion.  Its elements are `std::shared_ptr`s to `DataCell` objects.  Here is the code in the header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <memory>

class DataCell
{
public:
    double _cartesianDistance;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<DataCell> DataCellPtr;

bool operator<(const DataCellPtr &d1, const DataCellPtr &d2)  {
    std::cout << "lalala" << std::endl;
    return d1->_cartesianDistance < d2->_cartesianDistance;
}

typedef std::multiset<DataCellPtr, std::less<DataCellPtr>> DataCellPtrMultiset;

int main(){
    DataCellPtr d1( new DataCell );
    DataCellPtr d2( new DataCell );
    d1->_cartesianDistance = 1.0;
    d2->_cartesianDistance = 2.0;
    DataCellPtrMultiset dms;
    dms.insert( d1 );
    dms.insert( d2 );
}
```

Expected output:

```
lalala
lalala
```

All works fine, except that my custom ordering does not take place, as I was supposed to get `"lalala"`s printed to my `std::out`, which is not happening.  I imagine the multiset is using the `shared_ptr`'s default ordering.  The `_cartesianDistance` member is a double.  Question: how do I override the default `shared_ptr` ordering?

Comment: Pretty sure the culprit here is ADL. It's looking for `operator<` in the scope where `std::shared_ptr` is defined (`namespace std`). Provide a custom comparator instead.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? There are important details missing.

Comment: @Barry There you go.

Comment: That was the solution, not the initial problem.

Comment: Yes... I noticed that.  I was about to change it.  No I have to redo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `std::less`, just supply your own comparator object:

```
struct DataCellPtrComparison
{
  bool operator() (const DataCellPtr &d1, const DataCellPtr &d2) const {
    std::cout << "lalala" << std::endl;
    return d1->_cartesianDistance < d2->_cartesianDistance;
  }
};

typedef std::multiset<DataCellPtr, DataCellPtrComparison> DataCellPtrMultiset;
```

"Overriding" the existing `operator<` for `std::shared_ptr` in your own namespace is not possible as it is already defined in `namespace std` and will be found there via [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) before any function with the same signature in a different namespace.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that (previous definition). Though, I was expecting the compiler (GCC 4.8) to complain (multiple definition).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't compile.  That type of operator expects only the right-hand side argument. The left-hand side would be an object of `DataCellPtrComparison` type.

Comment: @JeJo hit the nail.

Comment: I just don't understand how that (a `()` operator instead of a "rightful" `<` one) works...

Comment: `operator<` as member would let you compare different `DataCellPtrComparison` objects. That is not what you want. You want to use such an object just like `std::less` - as functor, i.e. something that you can "invoke" with some parameters and get a result. That is, `DataCellPtrComparison compare; bool isLess = compare(ptr1, ptr2);`.